# C# WPF ReactiveUI Toggle Layout - Method is called but it has no effect on the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui

In my XAML I have a ContextMenu where the MenuItems are associated with commands:

```
<ToolBarTray Background="Black" Width="180" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
    <ToolBar Background="Black">
        <ToolBar.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="10,0,54,25" />
        </ToolBar.Clip>
        <ToggleButton Checked="DropdownButton_Checked" MouseRightButtonUp="DropdownButton_MouseRightButtonUp" Background="Black" Margin="-4,-6,4,0">
            <ToggleButton.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Layout" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Path Margin="4" Width="5" Fill="White" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ToggleButton.Content>
            <ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">
                    <MenuItem Header="1x1" Command="{Binding MenuItem1}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="2x2" Command="{Binding MenuItem2}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="3x3" Command="{Binding MenuItem3}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="1+5" Command="{Binding MenuItem4}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
       </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

I use these commands to toggle the layout of another part of the markup, e.g. Layout1 looks like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Opacity="{Binding Layout1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" />
</Grid>
```

For this I have the following code in the view model:

```
public int Layout1 { get; set; }

public IReactiveCommand MenuItem1 { get; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    MenuItem1 = ReactiveCommand.Create(OnMenuItem1);
}

internal void OnMenuItem1()
{
    Layout1 = 100;
    Layout2 = 0;
    Layout3 = 0;
    Layout4 = 0;
}
```

And the same for Layout2, Layout3, Layout4.

Now when running this with the debugger I see that when I select "1x1" from the menu, OnMenuItem1 is executed. But the layout is not displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private int _layout1;

public int Layout1 { get => _layout1; set { RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _layout1, value); } }
```